# ASP.Net Core Swagger How to ignore default parameter values

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Is there a way to "suppress" the way that SwaggerUI pre-selects default values for optional parameters?  We still want these parameters to be included in the generated documentation, just without a value selected. This is the way it worked within SwaggerUI 2.x, but it looks like this is no longer the case with 3.x

**Edit - Adding example to clarify my question.**

As an example - let's say that you have the following endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
public dynamic GetSomething(
     string filter1, 
     string filter2, 
     bool shouldIFilter = false, 
     SomeEnum enumValue = SomeEnum.Whatever)
```

In swagger, when you click on "Try it out", the *shouldIFilter* and *enumValue* input fields will have the default values as specified in the method signature already selected. 
Instead, I want these fields to not have any value selected, so that they are **not** included in the query when you click on execute.

Basically, the request url should look like: http://some.url.com/v3/search?filter1=afilter&filter2=anotherfilter

(without the &shouldIFilter=false&enumValue=Whatever)

--- EDIT: 05/20/2019 ---

Taking Helder's suggestion below I tried injecting js to handle this. The first thing that I found is that the input fields do not exist until the "Try it out" button is clicked.  And this button does not exist until you expand the specific Operation in the list!?!  However, after wiring up an observer to set the values as I wanted when the elements were added to the DOM I am able to successfully change the selected value.

**But** when you click on Execute, these values refresh to match the original spec - and my js does not fire again to change the values that I want them to be.

I am starting to think that maybe this isn't possible. Though I am thinking that I may try and create a SwaggerUI plugin that might be able to do this - but I do not anticipate a lot of success there either.

Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe what I am looking for is how to have the parameter fields in Swagger UI with default values be different than what the signature shows

Comment: Nope it does not make any sense, if you have a default value that is what the UI should show, but you can make any changes you want using an IDocumentFilter

Comment: You are right - that does not make sense.  What I mean to say is that I want the correct default values to be documented.  I dont want to change the contract - all I want is parameters with a default value to not be included in the request URL, unless you select a value explicitly.  Looking at an older version of our API, before updating to .net core, it used to do this

Comment: Look into the inject JS I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 2):

To close the loop on this I wanted to share what I ended up doing to resolve this issue (though we have not decided if we are going to actually move forward yet).

Trying to inject JS ended up being too much hassle, due to Swagger UI 3.x using react - I was able to change the selected values in the UI for the specific parameters, but once you clicked on "execute" they "reset" back to the default values.

Instead, I ended up adding an IParameterFilter to change the parameter defaults, and made sure that each parameter was otherwise documented correctly to display what the default value is

```
public void Apply(OpenApiParameter parameter, ParameterFilterContext context)
{
   if (parameter.In != ParameterLocation.Query) return;

   // readonly list to limit which parameters have this applied
   if (_parametersToUnSet.Contains(parameter.Name))
   {
       parameter.Description = $"*Default value*: {parameter.Schema.Default}";
       parameter.Schema.Default = null;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've been using the default values to document a parameter...
You should be using the description field for that, here is an example:

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "x.lat",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "**Latitude**: a geographic coordinate that specifies the north–south position of a point on the Earth's surface.",
        "required": false,
        "type": "number",
        "format": "float",
        "maximum": 90,
        "minimum": -90
    },
    {
        "name": "x.lon",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "**Longitude**: a geographic coordinate that specifies the east-west position of a point on the Earth's surface.",
        "required": false,
        "type": "number",
        "format": "float",
        "maximum": 180,
        "minimum": -180
    }
],
```

That in the swagger-ui will look like:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Location#/Location/Location_Get2

The code for that model is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Models/Location.cs

---

If keeping the default values is a must, you will have to [inject JS](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/c8d8edbf1a04ccf5662ad961fd373adaf0d12e32/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/SwaggerUIOptionsExtensions.cs#L31) in swashbuckle to disable that functionality, but that could break if the UI changes

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify.  Not looking to add documentation in the input field.  I just dont want any value selected by default

Comment: OK - I have been trying to inject javascript as suggested.  I have gone through multiple posts on this, as well as the documentation that you link to.  I cannot get this to work.  I have confirmed that the namespace is correct, and pointing to the folder/filename as directed.  However, I am still getting 404 error when loading SwaggerUI.  

I am not clear on how embedded resources work in regards to being able to access them from within a web page, how does this actually work?

Comment: Can you create a sample project on GitHub reproducing your issue?

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work by adding a wwwroot/ext folder with my js file, and using "/" in the path instead of "."

Now I have found out that the input fields dont exist until you click on "Try it out", and the Try it out button does not exist until you expand the specific "Operation" that you are looking at!